# Get the GridViewColumn Header starting from a TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

```
                        <GridViewColumn Header="#ErrorRepeat1" Width="100">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding NoErrorRepeat1}"
                                             TextAlignment="Center"
                                             IsReadOnly="True"
                                             Background="{Binding IsPresentGroup1, Converter={StaticResource BoolToColorConverter}}"                                                                                          >
                                        <TextBox.ContextMenu>
                                            <ContextMenu>
                                                <MenuItem Header="Highlight Activity" Click="menuActivityFocus"/>
                                            </ContextMenu>
                                        </TextBox.ContextMenu>
                                    </TextBox>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
```

I am trying the get the GridViewColumn Header starting from the TextBox using :

```
 MenuItem mi = sender as MenuItem;
        var menu = mi.Parent as ContextMenu;
        if (menu != null)
        {
            TextBox tb = menu.PlacementTarget as TextBox;
            var gv = FindVisualParent<GridViewColumn>(tb);
        }
```

but no success with this approach.

I need some hint on how to access the GridViewColumn to get the header content.

Comment: What do you want to do with the `Header`?

Comment: @||| That header represents a property in some of my objects. I can iterate over the list of properties, and when i get an equality between a property name and the header, i can set that value with the TextBox.Text property.That's about it.

Comment: @Olaru - See if this works for you - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/69d7238a-e709-450b-a054-f44fb86280f4/how-do-i-find-out-which-gridviewcolumn-i-just-lost-focus-from?forum=wpf.

Answer (score 0):

You can data bind a value to the `Header` property and then access the data bound property from your code behind. Try something like this:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="{Binding ColumnHeader}" Width="100">
    ...
</GridViewColumn>
```

...

```
MenuItem mi = sender as MenuItem;
var menu = mi.Parent as ContextMenu;
if (menu != null)
{
    string columnHeader = ColumnHeader;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Who would that ColumnHeader be? I have many GridViewColumns in GridView. Should i have many string properties for column namings ? How can i make the connection between my TextBox and the column it resides in?